# How is an event translated from the OS to the application?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Let's say I have a button class like so:

```
class SpecicalButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);

    }

}
```

The overriding method will notify all the listeners of the click, by invoking the `Click` delegate.

But my question is, how does the `OnClick` method get called? There surely needs to be some type of checking for the button dimensions and whether or not the click was in its range.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The operating system handles all of the messages then sends msg's to the active window when keys are pressed.

All of the code processing the messages is abstracted from you in the lower layers of the .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given the fact that [most Windows Forms controls are native Windows controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16183326/1119545), they are all subjected to message handling (as [described in the link posted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx) in the comments) through [`Control.WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx).

When a Window message is posted to each control's message queue (by the main window's WndProc, which is the entry point for all messages) it is handled by it's window proc. If you look at the source code for `Control.WndProc` you will see that a lot of Windows messages are handled by private `Wm*` methods. These, in turn, translate each native message to a managed event by calling `OnSomethingHappened` (which actually calls the event handler for that specific event).

Now, buttons are native controls and they have their own override of `WndProc`. If you look at the [`ButtonBase` source code in referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonBase.cs), you'll see this in `WndProc`:

```
case NativeMethods.BM_CLICK:
    if (this is IButtonControl) {
        ((IButtonControl)this).PerformClick();
    }
    else {
        OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    return;
```

This takes you to `Control.OnClick` where the event handler is called.

Anyway, to answer your question... Hit testing is done way earlier, before the message is created and posted to a windows' message queue.

Comment: Thanks. The way it calls `OnSomethingHappend` of which calls the specific event makes me think it is very similar to the command design pattern.

Comment: @William: Not sure if they thought of that when they implemented it, but yes, it could be seen like a variation of the command pattern.